# JBoss Drools Requirements

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, drools

I've been trying on multiple machines, with multiple versions of Eclipse, JBoss Drools, and the Eclipse GEF (as stated in Drools docs as required).

I can't get them installed and working together, at all. See below for exact problem.

[image]

Comment: In order I installed:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

then 

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/gef4/updates/releases

then

http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Beta2/org.drools.updatesite/

Comment: What do you see when you choose "Show original error and build my own solution:"? That could give us a clue as to which plug-ins are incompatible with each other and why.

Comment: For the record, I'm running Luna SR2, GEF 3.9.100.201408150207, and Drools 6.2.0.Final with no issues.

Comment: Sure thing Erick - Not sure how to upload a 2nd screenshot here so I uploaded it to my Twitter: https://twitter.com/GoheX/status/620481453244059648/photo/1

I might try those versions then. Wish it was a bit more informative.

Comment: Any beta release is "experts only". You might try the Drools usage list. Does it work using 6.2.0-Final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question text you refer to Drools, but not jBPM. The install is choking on jBPM. Perhaps try installing Drools without the jBPM stuff? I'm running Drools 6.2.0.Final on Luna SR2 without issues, and I don't have jBPM installed.

If you still have problems there, you could try what @laune suggested: Drools 6.2.0.Final.