# Missing requirement: Drools Eclipse Plug-in 6.3.0.Beta2 requires 'bundle org.kie.eclipse 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, installation, drools

I'm trying to install the Drools plugin in Eclipse. I followed the steps as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch03.html) but I was only able to download the Guvnor items (2 out of 8).

After searching for the plugin in Install New Software using [this link](http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Beta2/org.drools.updatesite/), the Drools package appears. I check it and click Next. And then, no matter what I do, I keep receiving the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: JBoss Drools Core 6.3.0.Beta2 (org.drools.eclipse.feature.feature.group 6.3.0.Beta2)
>
> Missing requirement: Drools Eclipse Plug-in 6.3.0.Beta2 (org.drools.eclipse 6.3.0.Beta2) requires 'bundle org.kie.eclipse 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: JBoss Drools Core 6.3.0.Beta2 (org.drools.eclipse.feature.feature.group 6.3.0.Beta2)
>
> To: org.drools.eclipse [6.3.0.Beta2]

Can anyone help me with this error?

Much appreciated,

-J.

Comment: Following a quite old (5.2 *is* old) howto for installing 6.3.0 may not be a good idea. Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373222/jboss-drools-requirements

Comment: @laune I wish I'd seen that question earlier, it would have saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the download link was wrong. I was downloading the Beta version instead of the newest version.

For those who encounter the same problem, use this link instead:
http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/